# How to start a rails server by ip with a specific host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ngrok

I have a rails application that responds to different domains, that is, it has different layouts for each possible domain. In local development, so that I can visualize each of these layout responses, I did the following:

I navigated through the folders to etc/hosts and entered the domains that I want to be able to access my application locally. It looked like this:

127.0.0.1   localhost domain1.eng.br domain2.com.br domain3.com.br

And this really works, I can access my application from these domains, but only when I launch my application from localhost (just typing rails s)

I need to make my application public to all devices on my network and for that, I need to launch the application from my IP, but when I do this, I cannot access my application from these different domains

How to do this? Preferably so that I don't need to install any gems or anything like that. I thought about using ngrok, but I don't know how to do this using it either.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rails server -b 0.0.0.0`

It's works for me in my websites in the cloud.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).